# Prove the relation $\mathcal{L}u - L_h u = O(h^2)$ for $h \to 0$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, taylor-expansion

**Exercise:** Prove the relation $$\mathcal{L}u - L_h u = O(h^2)\,\, \text{for} \,\,h \to 0,$$ for sufficiently smooth functions $u$ for the standard five-point discretization
$$-\Delta_h = \frac{1}{h^2}\begin{bmatrix}
& -1 & \\
-1 & 4 & -1 \\
& -1 &\\
\end{bmatrix}_h$$
of the operator $\mathcal{L} = - \Delta$ using Taylor expansion.

**Question:** how do I solve/handle this?

I have no idea what to do, thanks in advance!

Comment: What is $L_h u$?

Comment: @Stefan it's the discretization of $\mathcal{L}$!:)

Answer (score 0):

On the one hand, $-\mathcal{L}$ is the Laplace operator, i.e. $-\mathcal{L}u = u_{xx} + u_{yy}$. On the other hand, $-L_h$ is the finite-difference approximation of $-\mathcal{L}$, obtained by centered differencing of the second derivatives $u_{xx} \simeq (u_{i+1,j} - 2u_{i,j} + u_{i-1,j})/h^2$ and $u_{yy} \simeq (u_{i,j+1} - 2u_{i,j} + u_{i,j-1})/h^2$, where $u_{i,j}\simeq u(ih,jh)$. For each approximation, we know --or we obtain by Taylor series expansion as $h\to 0$, see e.g. [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2391727/finite-difference-second-derivative-error-analysis)-- that the finite difference formula is second-order accurate, which ends the proof.