# Limit of the approximation of the laplacian

Tags: limits, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, laplacian

We were given the following function:

$$Q(h)\equiv\frac{f(x+h,y)+f(x-h,y)+f(x,y+h)+f(x,y-h)-4f(x,y)}{h^2}$$

which is the approximation of the laplacian of $f$ at $x$ and $y$ and asked to find the limit of $Q(h)$ as $h\to0$ in terms of the partial derivatives of $f$.

I know that the definition for partial derivatives is

$$f_x(x,y)=\frac{f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)}h$ and $f_y(x,y)=\frac{f(x,y+h)-f(x,y)}h$$

and with this I can spread it out to

$\begin{aligned}\lim_{h\to 0}Q(h)&= \lim_{h\to0}\frac1h\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)}h+ \lim_{h\to0}\frac1h\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x-h,y)-f(x,y}h+ \lim_{h\to0}\frac1h\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x,y+h)-f(x,y)}h + \lim_{h\to0}\frac1h\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x,y-h)-f(x,y)}h\end{aligned}$

and then, from there get

$\begin{aligned}\lim_{h\to0}Q(h)&= \lim_{h\to0}\frac1hf_x(x,y)+\lim_{h\to0}\frac1h\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x-h,y)-f(x,y)}h+ \lim_{h\to0}\frac1hf_y(x,y) + \lim_{h\to0}\frac1h\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x,y-h)-f(x,y)}h,\end{aligned}$

but I get stuck with this: $\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac1h$ which is basically infinity and also $\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{f(x-h,y)-f(x,y)}h$ and $\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{f(x,y-h)-f(x,y)}h$ don't know what to do with them.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2510467/418542)

Answer (score 0):

This should help.

$\frac {\partial f}{\partial x} = \lim_\limits{h\to0} \frac {f(x+h,y) - f(x,y)}{h}\\
\frac {\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} = \lim_\limits{h\to0} \frac {(f(x+h,y) - f(x,y)) - (f(x-h,y) - f(x))}{h^2}$

Comment: I edited my question once I remembered the definition for the partial derivatives, but I'm curious where you got the formula for the second partial derivative fxx(x,y) as I can't find any documentation to show me fyy(x,y) online and i didn't know either.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_derivative#Limit